# SyntaxError: f-string: expecting '}' in python

Tags: python, class

```
def get_descriptive_name(self):
    long_name = f"{self.year} {self.make = make} {self.model = model}"
    return long_name.title()
    print(long_name)
```

i dont know whats going on with my code. Anyone can help me please? i just started to learn about classes in python and i found this error sytax. I really happy if you can help me out. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 5):

You cannot include `=` in `f''` strings. I think this is what you meant to do -

```
self.make,self.model=make,model
long_name = f"{self.year} {self.make} {self.model}"
```

Comment: yess, thank you for that. I just copy it from __init__ and i'm forget to remove the =